# Overload with first optional parameter

Tags: typescript, overloading

How can I implement following logic?

```
function test(data: {x}, f: Function);
function test(f: Function);

function test(data: {x}, f: Function) {
    if (!f) {
        f = data;
        data = {x: 111};
    }

    return f(data);
}

test({x: 17}, t => 0);
test(t => 0);
```

It compiles in a right way, but shows 2 errors.

```
function test(data, f) {
    if (!f) {
        f = data;
        data = { x: 111 };
    }
    return f(data);
}
test({ x: 17 }, function (t) { return 0; });
test(function (t) { return 0; });
```

A place to test: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

PS: [Same question in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467538/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Comment: @Igor, not related to the question. I'm asking about compilation, not about call examples.

Comment: @Igor, I've updated the question to prevent misunderstanding.

Comment: "TypeScript is a typed superset of J...". Imagine, in any strongly typed language you declare a variable `string a;` and assign `a = 1.2;`. Will it let you?

Comment: @Igor, but in typescript you have to implement a single function body and it does support overloads. So I expect that there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
function test(data: {x}, f: Function);
function test(f: Function);

//function test(data: {x} | Function, f?: Function) {
function test(data, f?) {
    if (!f) {
        f = data as Function;
        data = {x: 111};
    }

    return f(data);
}
```

The following calls are ok:

```
test({x: 17}, t => 0);
test(t => 0);
```

And the following aren't:

```
test({x: 17});
test(0);
test(t => 0, t => 0);
```

Any of these ways seems ok:

```
function test(data: {x} | Function, f?: Function) {
function test(data, f?) {
```

And explicit type cast is required:

```
f = data as Function;
```